# When is the memory in the cpp vector deallocated?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, vector, destructor

Say I have a function `fooRead(void **data)` in a.cpp which declares a "`vector<FOO> x`" and reads 100 foo objects from a file. Say I call fooRead from "b.cpp", and pass a reference to "`void* data;`" using `fooRead(&data);`

In foo.cpp I do `*data = x.data()` . Now after now as the function fooRead ends the vector goes out of scope and would have been automatically destroyed. So does that mean data in b.cpp is pointing to memory which I should not now use??

I am quite confused on when and how are vectors destroyed (automatic destructor called). Any help is really really appreciated. I am kindoff stuck!

Comment: can you paste some code? I believe case would be easier to understand then...

Comment: please don't describe what the code does. Show the relevant code (don't interpret this as dumping your whole 100 lines code)

Comment: `void **data` _Why_? C++ has a very good type system. Learning to use it will make you a better C++ programmer. The destructor of a `std::vector` is called when the object goes out of scope. Just like every other destructor.

Comment: @PiotrNycz :  I am calling a cpp function (extern C) from a Genetic algorithm C library we previously coded. There is a lot of cryptic code that is difficult to explain over the question without making it too long to read.

Comment: @Tim : because I want the data in b.cpp to point to the instances of FOO. Had I passed the only var data, I would have ended up doing nothing to the actual location data in b.cpp. Please think it over

Comment: @PrakharAgrawal you can also pass pointers of other types than `void`, like a pointer or reference to a `vector<FOO>`s.

Comment: @PrakharAgrawal when I see `void**`, I immediately know that the code was written by a C programmer trying to apply C idioms to C++. C++ has a very nice type system, so `void*` is extremely rarely used in C++ (read almost never). Moreover, `void**` should never be used because C++ has NRVO and  C++11 has move semantics to make handling large data structures easy and cheap. Finally, C++ does not allow dereferencing `void*`, so some cast must be made along the way: the type in that cast should be brought to the interface of `fooRead` and `void**` abolished.

Comment: @CompuChip tim I call the function from a C program and hence can neither cast it into the FOO at the interface of fooRead and nor pass pointer to a vector<FOO>

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the data in b.cpp is pointing to freed memory (and freed memory should never be used). According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/%7Evector), the std::vector destructor

> Destructs the container. The destructors of the elements are called
>   and the *used storage is deallocated*.

So when the vector goes out of scope at the end of fooRead, its storage (the output of `data()`) is also freed.

Comment: What if I declare the vector as a global variable in file b.cpp? Will it stay in scope for all of the program ?

Comment: @PrakharAgrawal If you want to determine when memory get's allocated and de-allocated in global scope, why not just make a program that does it, so you can see yourself?

Comment: @Toppest.Of.Kek Hi, I actually tried this. But then the memory still had the stuff it had before freeing the vector (since feeing memory just tells OS to stop indexing it but does not 0 it out). I don't get to know should I be using this memory or not. In a larger program I get a bug on memory corruption which I am having trouble in locating. So I think this can be the problem.

Comment: @PrakharAgrawal You could either make the vector a global in b.cpp, or a static variable. Both of these have the problem that the next time you run fooRead, you will overwrite the original data, making it not very thread safe or easy to use. Could fooRead simply return a vector?

Comment: @SCFrench No it cannot return vector since the cpp function is being called from a C library. I understand making it global will overwrite the data the next time I call the function, but what do you mean by making it not very thread safe?

Comment: unsynchronized static variables are the bane of multithreading. Suppose two threads are calling fooRead at the same time. they'll each be writing to the same static vector, which will get totally messed up, possibly even crashing.